# Factory design pattern with AngularJS, is this the right way?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, design-patterns

I would like to implement Factory design pattern in AngularJS, so that the right kind of object can be created, but I'm not sure how that fits inside whole framework thing. Let's say there are different types of Products in AngularJS application, Clothing and Ebooks:

```
   Product
    |   |
Ebook  Clothing
```

and I would like to instantiate concrete type of object based on some criteria, for example type field returned from database, should I do that like this ? :

```
// pseudo-code
ProductController
 Factory.createObject(type)
```

If that's OK, is it ok to store Factory function inside that controller and where should I store concrete constructor objects that represent products(like function Ebook()) ?

Answer (score 0):

I'd imagine you should dependency inject your Factory into your controller.

- https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di.

These might give you an ideas of how to organize:

- http://scotch.io/tutorials/javascript/angularjs-best-practices-directory-structure
- http://cliffmeyers.com/blog/2013/4/21/code-organization-angularjs-javascript

Comment: Yeah, I realized that too, that factory method should be inside, Factory. But, what still bugs me is what to do with custom types(Ebook, Product). Seems that your second link offers some answers, thanks.